# How to concatenate multiple php variables within Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, concatenation

Hello I am trying to utilize geomapping within in my website and I'm having trouble dynamically pulling the address for a restaurant and putting it into my javascript. I am using the get method to pull the restaurant_id from the url and then use this to pull the restaurant's complete address. This is the line of code I am having trouble with (var destinationAddress):

```
$con=mysqli_connect("root","");
        $rest_id2=$_GET['id'];
        $rest_id=(int)$rest_id2;
        $sql="SELECT * from restaurant WHERE restaurant_id='".$rest_id."'";
        $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        $rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    //exit early if no geolocation
    if(!navigator.geolocation) return;

    var destinationAddress = "<?php echo $rows['address'].$rows['city'].$rows['state'].$rows['zip']; ?>";
</script>
</head>
....
```

Any one know see what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: How should that variable look when PHP is done rendering?

Comment: What is the error/problem?

Comment: The variable should look like "3334 South Shore Lane Cary, North Carolina 27519"

Comment: I guess I forgot commas also

Comment: i assuming restaurant_id is a int datatype in that case DONT quote it in your SQL.

Comment: You also forgot the spaces, at least I guess you did. Could you please add example input and output *to your question*?

Comment: And what does it *actually* look like in the rendered page? I suspect the query is just not returning any rows so you are just outputting a series of nulls, i.e. nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your life easier: build the destination address outside of the template:

```
$rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if( $rows !== NULL )
{
    $destinationAddress = "{$rows['address']}, {$rows['city']}, {$rows['state']}, {$rows['zip']}";
}
else
{
    // no rows! (anomaly)
    $destinationAddress = "no destination address available";
}

// due to the way you'll later inject the variable
// into JavaScript code double quotes must be escaped

$destinationAddress = str_replace( '"', '\"', $destinationAddress );
```

---

Then simply

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //exit early if no geolocation
    if(!navigator.geolocation) return;

    var destinationAddress = "<?=$destionationAddress?>";
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the commas and spaces.

```
var destinationAddress = "<?php echo $rows['address'].$rows['city'].$rows['state'].$rows['zip']; ?>";
```

Answer (score 0):

becase u forgot to **close** the function `})` , try

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    //exit early if no geolocation
    if(!navigator.geolocation) return;

    var destinationAddress = "<?php echo $rows['address'].$rows['city'].$rows['state'].$rows['zip']; ?>";
})
</script>
```